# No Information was found about this pixel format - WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying to display an image in my code. I have given the location of the image i added in imagesource. This gives me the above error.
     
     
        
     
    
But when i change the image file name to an already exiting image file in the image folder say file1.png, it works fine. what is it that i am doing wrong? i tried to add different files in this folder, all have issues except the exiting ones

Comment: <Image name = "xxx"><Image.Source>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="..\images\File.png"/>
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding a comment.

Comment: "when i change the image file name to an already existing image file ... it works". Does "..\images\File.png" not exist? That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, but it looks like its a "convoluted error" thrown by WPF for "image not found"! I corrected my image path (in my case, its a relative resource, so just added the missing dot) and the error disappeared! I couldn't believe it at first, but I was convinced when I was able to repro this bug just by replacing the `UriSource` with bad path, again and again!

```
   <Image Width="200" Height="32">
       <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="200" DecodePixelHeight="32" UriSource=".\Resources\Image\logo.png" />
       </Image.Source>
   </Image>
```

Check your image path, or make sure the image file name matches the one specified in the `UriSource`; it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are not being very specific in your question so hard to answer. Could be an error in the image. Try opening the picture in photoshop or the like to see if any errors appear.
Or try checking the properties of the image. Build action should be Resource but is sometimes set to Content when added to the project.

Hope this help you. This have given me lots of headaces before anyways :)

Comment: I am sorry to confuse you. But here is the situation.. I added 5-6 images in the project. Some I created myself and some I downloaded. None of them work. All give me the same error. However, when I give the name of an image which was already present in the project (project has been going on for few years now by the way and I have started working on it), it works. I don't understand how. Is it possible that all the images I used are buggy? One more thing.. All the images old/new are at the same location. I just change the image name..